# Skipped loading plugin with error: XML Document '.../nodelet_plugins.xml' has no Root Element. This likely means the XML is malformed or missing

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I issue this command:

```
roslaunch stdr_launchers server_with_map_and_gui_plus_robot.launch
```

And the get the error:

```
[ERROR] [1516990762.757066973]: Skipped loading plugin with error: XML Document '/opt/ros/kinetic/share/gmapping/nodelet_plugins.xml' has no Root Element. This likely means the XML is malformed or missing..
```

Seems like that's not supposed to be happening. Any ideas?

[See screenshot.png](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/ros/15169907091279709.png)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/280982/skipped-loading-plugin-with-error:-xml-document-%27/opt/ros/kinetic/share/gmapping/nodelet_plugins.xml%27-has-no-root-element.-this-likely-means-the-xml-is-malformed-or-missing./) by [pitosalas](https://answers.ros.org/users/30692/pitosalas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 628 on 2018-01-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please see #q274849.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-01-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pitosalas](https://answers.ros.org/users/30692/pitosalas/) on 2018-01-26**:
Thanks. And thanks to @jayess for using your copious free time to correct my original question ;)